# Monitoring nexus OSS 3.0.1

Tags: nexus, datadog

I have some doubts regarding monitoring nexus OSS 3.0.1 server. Can some please let me know the following:-

1. Are there any health check REST APIs available which we can query to get the health of overall nexus OSS server and for individual repo? I have seen this [link](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html). But couldn't find any REST API for health check?
2. I am able to see "Metrics Core bundle" `Active` under `Bundles`. Can someone let me know if there is a way I can listen to these metrics?
3. Are there any plugin / integration avaiable for [datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com)?
4. In general how do people generally monitor nexus oss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus 3.0.1 exposes authenticated access to metrics using http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/servlets/
You have these endpoints available for different purposes:

        `{host:port}/service/metrics/healthcheck
        {host:port}/service/metrics/data
        {host:port}/service/metrics/ping
        {host:port}/service/metrics/threads`